# How can I convert my python program into a web app on PythonAnywhere?

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, pythonanywhere

I have made a python program. Out of curiosity, I want to implement it on a website so that my friends or anyone can run it without seeing the code directly.
Here's the [Github link](https://github.com/rafisics/memorize-your-move/blob/master/project_v3.py) of my program code. 
I have opened a free account on PythonAnywhere and added a new web app with the Flask framework.
It has a default file `flask_app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello from Flask!'
```

I have uploaded my `.py` file too. Having no experience with Python web apps, I've looked at the articles about Flask. Seems I need to translate my python code into some different structure. But I can't figure out how to connect and modify my `.py` file to the flask structure.

Can you kindly tell me how can I do so? Or is there any easy way else such that I just need to paste my python program into a file and it will be automatically implemented as a web app?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just put this code into your flask api. There needs to be client rendering as well.
What you are looking for is a .io type web game.
Have a look at https://victorzhou.com/blog/build-an-io-game-part-1/
This article details the steps required for a browser based game.

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a lot of work involved in turning an interactive script like that into a website, but it is possible.  [This tutorial](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/169/) on the PythonAnywhere blog has a step-by-step guide that works up to a website that takes a series of inputs across multiple pages, and produces an output, so it might be a good starting point.